# How to pass an ArrayList and an integer to a new activity (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm having a problem with starting a new activity once I give the intent an ArrayList of songs, my code is here:

```
ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();

songs.add(new Song("title", "artist"));

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Game.class);

int dif = 0;

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
if (songs != null) {
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("DEVICE_SONGS", songs);

    bundle.putInt("DIFFICULTY", dif);

    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    }

startActivity(intent);
```

Song already implements Parcelable.

When `startActivity` runs, `Game` activity does not start, instead, it goes up to the parent activity with no error in the logs.

I have tried this without adding `bundle` to the `intent`, and the correct activity starts.

Any help with this is appreciated, thanks

**EDIT**

I have now tried with `putParcelableArrayListExtra()` as follows:

```
if (songs != null) {
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("DEVICE_SONGS", songs);

    intent.putExtra("DIFFICULTY", dif);
    }
```

and I have the same issue. I don't try to access the extras on the new activity either.

**EDIT 2**

After some more testing (on a virtual device), it actually works, so I'm thinking this is to do with the device I'm using (Oneplus X with Oxygen OS). So now the question is, how do I get it to work on all devices?

Comment: Try with putParcelableArrayListExtra. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList<? extends android.os.Parcelable>)

Comment: @MiguelBenitez Thank you! This works on the Virtual device, (but not mine)

Comment: You could try to send an Parcelable Array instead of an ArrayList. Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit to the amount of data which can be passed by an `Intent`, which is being exceeded here. If I limit the size of `songs`, there is no problem

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Add extended data to the intent.  The name must include a package
 * prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names
 * like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".
 *
 * @param name The name of the extra data, with package prefix.
 * @param value The ArrayList<Parcelable> data value.
 *
 * @return Returns the same Intent object, for chaining multiple calls
 * into a single statement.
 *
 * @see #putExtras
 * @see #removeExtra
 * @see #getParcelableArrayListExtra(String)
 */
public Intent putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value) {
    if (mExtras == null) {
        mExtras = new Bundle();
    }
    mExtras.putParcelableArrayList(name, value);
    return this;
}
```

***Package Name Prefix!***

Answer (score 0):

first of all your class Song must implements Parcelable, type this:

```
public class MyClass implements Parcelable {
    public final int num1;
    public final int num2;

    public MyClass(final int num1, final int num2) {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
    }

    public static final Creator<MyClass> CREATOR = new Creator<MyClass>() {
        public MyClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyClass(in);
        }

        public MyClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyClass[size];
        }
    };

    public vonum1 writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(num1);
        dest.writeInt(num2);
    }


    private MyClass(Parcel in) {
        num1 = in.readInt();
        num2 = in.readInt();
    }
}
```

Now you can use bundle.putParcelableArrayListExtra for pass your list to another activity.

For pass the ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();
songs.add(new Song("title", "artist"));
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Game.class);
bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("song", songs);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

For retrieve the ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Song> songs;
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("song")){
    songs = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("songs");
}
```

Comment: I have already implemented Parcelable (it says in my question), this is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could try to send an Parcelable Array instead of an `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<Parcelable> a =new ArrayList<Parcelable>();
Parcelable[] b = new Parcelable[a.size()];
a.toArray(b);
i.putExtra("YOUR_DATA_LIST",b);
```

Comment: This also works, but I have found my issue now, thank you for your help